# conditional operator "if" with several expressions

Tags: django

I have encountered a little problem during programming and don't know how to solve it. After several researches I turn into this web site to ask my question. It seems difficult to me to find an answer because I don't really know how searching.

In my django template, I just want to compare 2 expressions in the same conditional operator "if" and can't find a way to do it.<

> `{% if group.name!="admin" AND group.name!="-" %}` : Could not parse the remainder: '!="admin"' from 'group.name!="admin"'

I tried with also `&` and `&&` and get the same error.

Comment: You need to put spaces between the operators and your variables. `and` should also be lower cased.

Comment: so I get "Unused 'AND' at end of if expression." what is lower cased?

Comment: Don't put logic in templates, handle this in your view or in the group class.

Comment: well this does not response to my question. How can i do this in my view if this conditionnal operator manage the display of the site?

Comment: 'AND' needs to be lower cased: `{% if group.name != "admin" and group.name != "-" %}`. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/).

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  {% if group.name != "admin" and group.name != "-" %}
  <<<Put your markups here>>>
  {% endif %}
```

You are missing spaces around your operators and there is no `AND` operator, use `and` instead.

Comment: great.. happy coding.. :)